# Smallest Monotone Class Subset of Smallest Sigma-Algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, monotone-class-theorem

$\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal{A}}\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}$
I'm having trouble understanding the first step of the Monotone Class Theorem, which every proof I find seems to claim is obvious.

Here is a restatement of the theorem:

> **Monotone Class Theorem**. Suppose $\mathcal{\A_0}$ is an algebra.  Let $\A = \sigma\langle\A_0\rangle$ be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra
>   containing $\A_0$, and $\M$ be the smallest monotone class containing
>   $\A_0$.  Then, $\A = \M$.

I am unsure about the logic of the first part of the proof, which reads as follows:

> **Proof**: ($\M \subset \A$).
>   A $\sigma$-algebra is clearly a monotone class, so $\M \subset \A$.

I understand how to show that a $\sigma$-algebra is a monotone class, but cannot see why this necessitates the claim above.  It is also easy to see that $|\M| \leq |\A|$:

> **Proof**: ($|\M| \leq |\A|$).  Suppose $|\M|>|\A|$.  Then, $\M$ is not the smallest monotone class containing $\A_0$, because $\A$ is a monotone class.  This is a contradiction!

However, it is unclear to me how we can make any claim about the elements of $A$.  Is it not possible for $\M$ to contain an element not in $\A$?

Comment: I suspect that $\mathcal M$ equals the intersection of all monotone classes that contain $\mathcal A_0$. So it is a subset of each monotone class that contains $\mathcal A_0$ and $\mathcal A$ is one of them.

Comment: Oh wow, yes, I completely missed that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer turned out to be quite obvious after all:$\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal{A}}\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}$

> **Proof**:
>   Because the family of monotone classes is closed under intersection, the intersection of all monotone classes containing $\A_0$ must be the smallest such class:  $$\M = \cap S \qquad S \equiv \{ \mathcal{G} | \mathcal{G} \text{ is a monotone class}, \A_0 \subset \mathcal{G}\}$$
>   Because $\A$ is a monotone class and $\A_0 \subset \A$, we know $\A \in S$.  So, $\M \cap \A = \M$, and therefore $\M \subset \A$.

Thanks to drhab for filling in what I was missing.